# App slow down a lot when display data on a scrolling view

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiscrollview, combine

I am building an app with a scrolling view to create a feed. I have a view model that provide the data and the SwiftUI display it. As of now, I have followed a clean parttern and not pulling yet data from a backend. I created a `Mocked` file at repo level to decode and return a JSON file. The `json` file is stored locally.

Below is the code

SwiftUI view

```
struct FeedView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = FeedViewModel()
    @State private var isFeedSelected: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    if(isFeedSelected) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.feed) { post in
                            PostItemView(item: post)
                        }
                    } else {
                        ForEach(viewModel.classFeed) { classItem in
                            Text(classItem.userName)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 20)
            .onAppear {
                if(isFeedSelected) {
                    viewModel.getFeed()
                } else {
                    viewModel.getClasses()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            isFeedSelected = true
                        }) {
                            SelectButton(text: "Feed", isSelected: isFeedSelected == true)
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            isFeedSelected = false
                        }) {
                            SelectButton(text: "Classes", isSelected: isFeedSelected == false)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The viewmodel which provide the `feed` and `classes` are as below"

```
func getFeed() {
        feedUseCase
            .getFeed()
            .sink { res in
                switch res {
                case .failure(let err):
                    self.state = .error(error: err)
                default:
                    break
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] feedsValue in
                self?.feed = feedsValue
                self?.state = .success
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func getClasses() {
        feedUseCase
            .getClasses()
            .sink { res in
                switch res {
                case .failure(let err):
                    self.state = .error(error: err)
                default:
                    break
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] value in
                self?.classFeed = value
                self?.state = .success
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

For this example, I will just continue by just showing the `feed` part instead of `classes` but the code is basically the same.

UseCase file:

```
final class FeedUseCase {
    
    static let shared = FeedUseCase()
    
    let repository: FeedRepositoryProtocol
    
    init() {
        self.repository = FeedRepository.shared
    }
    
    func getFeed() -> AnyPublisher<[FeedItemEntity], Error> {
        return repository.getFeed()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func getClasses() -> AnyPublisher<[ClassItemEntity], Error> {
        return repository.getClasses()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
}
```

The Repository interface:

```
protocol FeedRepositoryProtocol {
    func getFeed() -> AnyPublisher<[FeedItemEntity], Error>
    func getClasses() -> AnyPublisher<[ClassItemEntity], Error>
}
```

```
final class FeedRepository: FeedRepositoryProtocol {
        
    static let shared = FeedRepository()
    
    #if MOCKED
        let service: MockedFeedService
    #else
        let service: FeedService
    #endif
    
    init() {
        
        #if MOCKED
            self.service =  MockedFeedService.shared
        #else
            self.service =  FeedService.shared
        #endif 

    }
    
    func getFeed() -> AnyPublisher<[FeedItemEntity], Error> {
        return service.getFeed().eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func getClasses() -> AnyPublisher<[ClassItemEntity], Error> {
        return service.getClasses().eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    
}
```

I have created a `mocked` scheme, so it's set `MOCKED` to true and use `MockedFeedService`

The `MockedFeedService` look like this:

```
class MockedFeedService: FeedServiceProtocol {
    
    static let shared = MockedFeedService()

    
    func getFeed() -> Future<[ios_foodloose_app.FeedItemEntity], Error> {
        return Future<[FeedItemEntity], Error> { promise in
            
            guard let url = Bundle(for: MockedFeedService.self).url(forResource: "basic-test-feed-response",withExtension: "json"),
                  let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                return promise(.failure(NSError(domain: "", code: 401, userInfo: [ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Error"])))
            }
            
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode( [FeedItemEntity].self, from: data)
                promise(.success(response))
            } catch {
                print("JSON Decode error: \(error)")
                promise(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
```

The `FeedItemEntity` looks like this:

```
struct FeedItemEntity: Codable {
    var ts: Int
    var userName: String
    var userLocation: String
    var userImageUrl: String
    var title: String
    var postImageUrl: String
    var postType: PostType
    var rating: Int
    var comments: CommentsEntity
    var likes: Int
    var hashTag: [String]
}
```

When I say it's slowing down, the app is unusable for 5 min.... then it works. If I tap of `classes` button to load classes, it starts again, it takes forever to load.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ? if the issue is that the code is running on the MainThread, can someone add an example on how to make it run on the background ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your MockedFeedService getFeed() function is executing on the main thread hence the slowness ?

Comment: @Petar how do I make sure it's running on a background thread? I am new in iOS dev

Comment: how many data do you have ?, and when it start slow down
only when switch feed or while scrolling ?

Comment: In SwiftUI it's best to use `assign` instead of `sink` so the lifetime of the pipeline is linked to the StateObject being init and deinit when the screen appears and disappears. However in general it is slower to use objects instead of just `View` struct hierarchy and the new `.task` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes encoding/decoding large amount of data on the main thread can cause hangs because it's pretty expensive. You can dispatch it to the background thread like this:

```swift
do {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        // this happens on the background thread
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode( [FeedItemEntity].self, from: data)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // this happens on the main thread
            promise(.success(response))
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("JSON Decode error: \(error)")
    promise(.failure(error))
}
```

You may also want to show a loader/progress view while the data is decoding.

Comment: I tried your solition but it now it says : Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.

Comment: @Seb where are you getting that error exactly? in the code above, we're dispatching the promise to the main thread so it shouldn't happen